# How to pass a null value using name/value pair in xml configuration file?

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

I have to pass a null value for a parameter through an xml configuration file to a function in the following forms

but in the value field I have to pass null as the value I an not able to canvass anything on the internet that allows me to pass null please help how do I pass null to the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the XML is being parsed when it is received.  If you are in control of the schema, a logical approach would be to simply omit the `<value>` element, and implement the parsing code to recognize the missing element as a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

While not talked about much... there is `xsi:nil`, [consider it's use in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
<options>
  <option name="foo" xsi:nil="true"/>
  <option name="bar">quux</option>
  <option name="qaaz"></option>
</options>
```

For instance, this might result in `foo -> null`, `bar -> "quux"`, and `qaaz -> ""`. Of course, it could have just as well been `isNull="true"` or encoded entirely differently....

...so the real question is related to *"what doesn't"* allow the use of `null`, because it can be encoded any which way, so long as everyone agrees.

Happy coding.